# How can I recursively check if a list is sorted in Lisp?

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a recursive function that checks the list and either returns true if the list is in ascending order or NIL otherwise. If the list is empty it is still true. I am completely new to Lisp, so its still very confusing.

```
(defun sorted (x)
  (if (null x)
      T
      (if (<= car x (car (cdr x)))
          (sorted (cdr x))
          nil)))
```

Comment: You're almost there, but you need to fix the syntax [e.g. (<= (car list) (car (cadr list))], and you'll need to handle the case where the list has only one element, not just no elements.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive version:

```lisp
(defun sorted (list)
  (or (endp list)
      (endp (cdr list))
      (and (<= (first list) (second list))
           (sorted (cdr list)))))
```

The more idiomatic loop-based predicate accepting a `:test` argument:

```lisp
(defun sortedp (list &key (test #'<=))
  (loop for (a b) on list
        while b
        always (funcall test a b)))
```

The version accepting a `:key`; we only call the `key` function once per visited element:

```lisp
(defun sortedp (list &key (test #'<=) (key #'identity))
  (loop for x in list
        for old = nil then new
        for new = (funcall key x)
        for holdp = T then (funcall test old new)
        always holdp))
```

Some tests:

```lisp
(loop for k in '(() 
                ((1)) 
                ((1) (2)) 
                ((2) (1)) 
                ((1) (2) (3)) 
                ((3) (2) (1)))
      collect (sortedp k :test #'> :key #'car))

=> (T T NIL T NIL T)
```

This one also works with other kinds of sequences:

```lisp
(defun sortedp (sequence &key (test #'<=) (key #'identity))
  (reduce (lambda (old x &aux (new (funcall key x)))
            (if (or (eq old t)
                    (funcall test old new))
                new
                (return-from sortedp nil)))
          sequence
          :initial-value t))
```

The above test gives:

```lisp
(T 1 NIL 1 NIL 1)
```

... which is a correct result thanks to generalized booleans.

Comment: @AryaAtighehchian Which environment are you using? Do you have any error message?

Comment: nvm i figured it out! is there anyway you can help me with other functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing your homework (seems so), then the above answers are fine. If you are just learning Lisp, and don't have constraints about recursivity, then the following might give you a glimpse about the power of Lisp:

```
(defun sorted (l) 
  (or (null l) (apply #'< l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your solution is the base case You need to stop not at the end of the list, but when looking at the last to elements, as you need to elements to do the comparison. Also the parens are missing in the call to `(car x)`

```
(defun sorted (list)
  (if (endp (cddr list))
      (<= (car list) (cadr list))
      (and (<= (car list) (cadr list))
           (sorted (cdr list)))))
```

Bare in mind that recursive solutions are discouraged in CL

Comment: It seems that this fails with a list of length 1.